# Silverlight ProgressBar Theme for WPF ProgressBar

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I tried using the `ProgressBar` style from the silverlight toolkit TwilightBlue theme in WPF. It doesn't throw any errors but the progress bar doesn't fill. The style is as follows.

```
<!-- ProgressBar -->
<Style TargetType="ProgressBar">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource TextBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFB4B4B4" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0.75,0.75,1.5,1.5" />
    <Setter Property="Maximum" Value="100" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
                <Grid x:Name="Root">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Determinate" />
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
                                <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="IndeterminateRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="DeterminateRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="IndeterminateGradientFill" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(LinearGradientBrush.Transform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].X">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:.5" Value="20" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                        </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                    </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border CornerRadius="4" x:Name="White" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="1.2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <RadialGradientBrush>
                                <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" ScaleX="1.35" ScaleY="1.35" />
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                            </RadialGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="ProgressBarTrack" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1.2,1.2,1.2,1.2" CornerRadius="4,4,4,4" Grid.RowSpan="2" Opacity="0.65" />
                    <Grid x:Name="ProgressBarRootGrid" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                        <Rectangle Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" x:Name="ProgressBarRootGradient" Canvas.ZIndex="1" Stroke="#FFFFFFFF" StrokeThickness="1" RadiusX="4" RadiusY="4" Opacity="0.65">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.7,1.263" StartPoint="0.699999988079071,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}" Offset="0.312" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource SecondaryColor}" Offset="1" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Grid x:Name="IndeterminateRoot" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <Rectangle Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" x:Name="IndeterminateSolidFill" Opacity="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Stroke="#FF448DCA" StrokeThickness="0" RadiusX="4" RadiusY="4" />
                            <Rectangle Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" x:Name="IndeterminateGradientFill" Opacity="0.7" StrokeThickness="1" RadiusX="4" RadiusY="4">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush MappingMode="Absolute" SpreadMethod="Repeat" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="20,1">
                                        <LinearGradientBrush.Transform>
                                            <TransformGroup>
                                                <TranslateTransform X="0" />
                                                <SkewTransform AngleX="-30" />
                                            </TransformGroup>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush.Transform>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset=".25" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0.85" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Margin="1" x:Name="DeterminateRoot">
                            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" x:Name="ProgressBarIndicator" StrokeThickness="0.5" RadiusX="4" RadiusY="4" Fill="{StaticResource PrimaryBrush}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <Border BorderBrush="#7FFFFFFF" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3.5" x:Name="InnerBorder" Margin="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
                    <Border CornerRadius="3.5" x:Name="Shadow" Margin="2" Opacity="0.2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                        <Border.OpacityMask>
                            <RadialGradientBrush>
                                <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="-0.5" />
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="0.3" />
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                            </RadialGradientBrush>
                        </Border.OpacityMask>
                        <Border.Background>
                            <RadialGradientBrush>
                                <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" ScaleX="1.75" ScaleY="2.25" />
                                        <TranslateTransform Y="0.65" />
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="0.55" />
                                <GradientStop Color="#4C000000" Offset="1" />
                            </RadialGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
                    <Border Margin="1" CornerRadius="4,4,40,40" x:Name="Highlight" Opacity="0.8" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,1">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <RadialGradientBrush>
                                <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" ScaleX="1.25" ScaleY="2" />
                                        <TranslateTransform Y="-0.6" />
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                <GradientStop Color="#BFFFFFFF" Offset="0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="#4CFFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                            </RadialGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Are the WPF and Silverlight progressbars different? Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues I see here:

**1. Your brush for the Foreground may not be defined. When you run this under the debugger, look for binding errors in the Output window.**

Try this changing

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource TextBrush}" />
```

to

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
```

If other parts are not showing up, you may have other undefined brushes.

**2. Your names may not match the PART names expected in WPF. Here is a custom progress bar style for WPF that may be a better starting point:**

```
<Style x:Key="ProgressBar-sterling" TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{x:Null}"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
        <Border Background="#00E6E6E6" BorderBrush="#FFA6A6A6" BorderThickness="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" >
          <DockPanel x:Name="PART_Track" LastChildFill="false">
            <Border x:Name="PART_Indicator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
              <Grid Margin="1">
                <Rectangle Fill="#FF737373" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
                <Rectangle x:Name="Overlay" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0.4" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
              <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                      <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1"/>
                      <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                      <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0.124"/>
                      <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.72"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
              </Grid>
            </Border>
          </DockPanel>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

One thing I would do it to create a sample Silverlight application and very any SL styles you import work in SL before trying to port them to WPF.  Also, Expression Blend provides example styles in both the Simple and SketchFlow styles and can make creating custom styles from existing controls much easier.